# Formatting nosetest output in Python

Tags: python, nose, nosetests

I am using the nosetests and have my directory structure as follows

```
repo
      package1
          sub1
             tests
                 test1.py
                 test2.py
      package2
          sub2
             tests
                 test3.py
                 test4.py
      package3
      package4
```

and if the test1.py is as below

```
class TestClass1(unittest.TestCase)
      def test_method1()

class TestClass2(unittest.TestCase)
      def test_method2()

class TestClass3(unittest.TestCase)
      def test_method3
```

The output of the nosetests run is as below

```
[Method name]  [modulename]. [ClassName] ... status
test_method1  (test1.TestClass1) ... ok
test_method2  (test1.TestClass2) ... ok
test_method3  (test1.TestClass3) ... ok
```

I would like to format this output to something like below

```
repo.package1.sub1 [package]                             SUCCESS
    test1.py [unit test file]                                SUCCESS
        TestClass1.test_method1 [unit test]                  SUCCESS
        TestClass2.test_method2 [unit test]                  SUCCESS
        TestClass3.test_method3 [unit test]                  SUCCESS
```

Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write your own nose plug in to control the output. There are two on this [page](https://nose-plugins.jottit.com/) which already do that: nose_machineout and nose-subunit. They would be a good starting point for you to look at.